# How do I trace database writes in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, trying to reverse-engineer an opaque application and duplicate some of its operations, so that I can automate some massive data loads.

I figured it should be easy to do -- just go into SQL Server Profiler, start a trace, do the GUI operation, and look at the results of the trace. My problem is that the filters aren't working as I'd expect. In particular, the "Writes" column often shows "0", even on statements that are clearly making changes to the database, such as `INSERT` queries.  This makes it impossible to set a `Writes >= 1` filter, as I'd like to do.

I have verified that this is exactly what's happening by setting up an all-inclusive trace, and running the app. I have checked the table beforehand, run the operation, and checked the table afterward, and it's definitely making a change to the table. I've looked through the trace, and there's not a single line that shows any non-zero number in the "Writes" column, including the line showing the `INSERT` query. The query is nothing special...  Just something like

```
exec sp_executesql 
    N'INSERT INTO my_table([a], [b], [c]) 
      values(@newA, @newB, @newC)',
    N'@newA int,@newB int,@newC int', @newA=1, @newB=2, @newC=3
```

(if there's an error in the above, it's my typo here -- the statement is definitely inserting a record in the table)

I'm sure the key to this behavior is in the description of the "Writes" column: "Number of **physical disk writes** performed by the server on behalf of the event." Perhaps the server is caching the write, and it happens outside of the Profiler's purvue. I don't know, and perhaps it's not important.

Is there a way to reliably find and log all statements that change the database?

Comment: Are you sure your trace is configured correctly? Are you looking at the start call instead of the complete call? You won't see stuff for the start because it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: which events are you filtering on? Could it work to do a wildcard filter on Textdata containing a wildcard search for Insert, Update and Delete. But as @Love2Learn says, you should certainly be sure to trace RPC Completed and SQL Batch Completed, not started.

Comment: I am using the "Standard (default)" template, which includes both `RPC:Completed` and `SQL:BatchCompleted` events.  Would a Textdata filter catch changes made from within a stored procedure?  I'm kind of new at this.

Comment: I came to the conclusion [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33189/insert-with-0-writes/33193#33193) that the Profiler Writes column actually shows the number of pages made dirty. If you write to a page that is already dirty then 0 zero writes are reported,

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a [Server Side Trace](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1035/sql-server-performance-statistics-using-a-server-side-trace/)?  It also works to document read and writes, which - if I'm reading you correctly - you are wanting to document writes.

Comment: That will report exactly the same as Profiler.